# Emberjs access controller value from a view

Tags: ember.js

There is a little something that bug me, I don't understand how this cannot works.

I have a lambda controller like this :

```
App.LambdaController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    myVar: null,

    [...]
    // Some function here and here
    [...]
});
```

And I have a view like that :

```
var MyRandomView = Em.View.extend({
    actions: {
        myAction : function(data) {
            this.set('controller.enquiry.myVar', data.something);
        }
    }
});
```

And after that I tried to display this data with a bind-attr helper but its doesn't work.

```
<img {{bind-attr src=App.LambdaController.myVar}}>
```

I mean I don't get anything inside my src in the img tag.

Am I doing this wrong ?

http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/841/

Comment: You define `LambdaController` then you call only `EnquiryController`, but you didn't post code for it. You can also setup demo on emberjs.jsbin.com - it would be even easier to help.

Comment: Woops, my bad its normally lambda, here a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/841/ . What I want to do is that, when you click in the view, this should set myVar with the data I have put from my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the lambdaController is the controller thats in scope, do this:

```
<img {{bind-attr src=myVar}}>
```

If controller is needed and used by controller in scope, do this:

```
<img {{bind-attr src=controllers.lambdaController.myVar}}>
```

Comment: hank you, this actually remove one problem, but myVar never change its value... Is `this.set('controller.lambda.myVar', data.something);` correct to set this variable ?

Comment: no actually I would do it like this: this.get("controller").set("enquiry.myVar", data.something)